# How to add response header when reaching static content using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, header, response

Adding a response header to a controller is easyPeasy enough like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(HttpServletResponse response)
{
 response.setHeader("specialheader", "Special Header");
 return "ok";
}
```

But that's not the case when the user tries to reach static content on the server (like a .css file), where I obviously don't want to create end points for each files.

So I tried to use a new class (@ControllerAdvice) which implements ResponseBodyAdvice, and overwriting the 'beforeBodyWrite' function I got the expected result for each queries which have end points.

The idea came from this [link](http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/20/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing/).

But when I try to reach a simple .css file on the server, the ControllerAdvice is not called, therefore the file opens in the browser without the expected headers set.

How can I add a general response header to every response going out of the server, including static files' responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply a filter. This will apply to every HTTP Request's response.

You can find the exact answer here:
[How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** There may be better options for Spring 2.x.

In my case (1.5.x), `FilterRegistrationBean` approach didn't add the additional headers to error pages; hence the alternative.

If you want such headers applied across **all static content** including error pages **and** regular static content (e.g. as part of a security audit/vulnerability assessment), you may have to follow a composite approach.

First, a simple utility class/method to keep the header addition uniform:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SecurityUtils {
    public static void addHtmlSecurityHeaders(HttpServletResponse response) {
        // some example content-security related headers
        response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "deny");
    }
}
```

This adds above headers to standard `static/` resources (courtesy of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261445/spring-boot-can-i-replace-resourcehttprequesthandler-with-my-own-implementation#43333113)):

```
    @Bean
    public ResourceHttpRequestHandler staticHandler() {
        ResourceHttpRequestHandler handler = new ResourceHttpRequestHandler() {
            @Override
            public void setHeaders(HttpServletResponse response, Resource resource, MediaType mediaType) throws IOException {
                SecurityUtils.addHtmlSecurityHeaders(response);
                super.setHeaders(response, resource, mediaType);
            }
        };
        handler.setLocations(Collections.singletonList(new ClassPathResource("static/")));
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping staticMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
        Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
        urlProperties.put("/**", "staticHandler");
        mapping.setMappings(urlProperties);
        return mapping;
    }
```

This adds above headers to **error pages**:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
                        SecurityUtils.addHtmlSecurityHeaders(response);
                    }
                });
            }

            // .. more overrides
        };
    }
```

Plus, some observations regarding other approaches:

- If you apply the headers at Spring Security level, they would not appear on *static* content such as the welcome page (base/index HTML) and error pages. (Unless you somehow configure/modify Spring Security to include static paths as well - which would of course be unnecessary, and probably impact performance)
- If you use only a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` to inject the headers, they will not appear Security-intercepted controller responses or (more importantly) on error pages.
- In `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` I tried configuring the headers on `preHandle()` and `afterCompletion()`; however they did not get applied for some scenarios - esp. for error pages.